# Diameter protocol library .net C# or java

Tags: java, c#-4.0, protocols, diameter-protocol

1. I'm looking for diameter protocol library on .net C#; Is there any opensource libraries?
2. Where can I download com.bea.wcp.diameter.* jar file for java (Eclipse IDE)?

Answer (score 1):

1. For Java you can look at [jdiameter](https://code.google.com/p/jdiameter/) which is the library used by Mobicents
2. Those jar's are part of Oracle Communications Converged Application Server